# SQL query: select into with join on 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2014 ...

I am trying to find the rows in table 'new' that do not exist in table 'old'.  I want to take these new rows and stuff them into a third table that I create.  Table 'new' has a primary key composed of two columns, MakeId and ModelId.  The following SQL runs, but gives me vastly too many rows.  Obviously, I am doing something wrong.

```
select 
   new.MakeId     ,
   new.MageMakeId ,
   new.ModelId    ,
   new.MageModelId
into BiUpdater..TranslateModel 
from Mage_Production..TranslateModel new
   left outer join BiLoader..TranslateModel old0 on new.MakeId  = old0.MakeId 
   left outer join BiLoader..TranslateModel old1 on new.ModelId = old1.ModelId 
go
```

Comment: You need a `where <some column> from old is null`. Otherwise you'll get back everything from new.

Comment: I realize that your question is  bit ambiguous.  Sample data and desired results are always helpful.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you want only one join using both columns:

```
select new.MakeId, new.MageMakeId, new.ModelId, new.MageModelId
into BiUpdater..TranslateModel 
from Mage_Production..TranslateModel new left outer join
     BiLoader..TranslateModel old
     on new.MakeId = old.MakeId and new.ModelId = old.ModelId
where old.MakeId is null;
```

More importantly, though, you need the `where` clause to get the non-matches.

EDIT:

If you are looking for rows that don't match either `MakeId` or `ModelId`, then perhaps this is really what you want:

```
select new.MakeId, new.MageMakeId, new.ModelId, new.MageModelId
into BiUpdater..TranslateModel 
from Mage_Production..TranslateModel new left outer join
     BiLoader..TranslateModel old1
     on new.MakeId = old1.MakeId left join
     BiLoader..TranslateModel old2
     on new.ModelId = old2.ModelId
where old1.MakeId is null and old2.ModelId is null;
```

You might want an `or` instead of `and`, in which case use `select distinct`.

Comment: Sweet!  Just what I needed!

I used the first example.  Sometimes a person gets going down the wrong path and you need a little straightening things out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SQL statement called EXCEPT that does this.  here is a link- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

Your right hand table would be 'new' and your left hand table would be 'old'.

```
select *
into BiUpdater..TranslateModel  
from (
select new.*
from Mage_Production..TranslateModel new

EXCEPT

select old.*
from BiLoader..TranslateModel old
)
```

Alternatively you could use a left join to do this:

```
select new.*
into BiUpdater..TranslateModel 
from Mage_Production..TranslateModel new left join BiLoader..TranslateModel old
on new.MakeId = old.MakeId and new.ModelId = old.ModelId
where old.MakeId is null
```